# class contains one element of subclasses

Tags: java, uml

Giving the diagram below, I want to know the following:

- How to make sure that a class car can have a GPS of type A or B not both?

[image: another example]

Comment: I guess you need to know how to implement the constraint specifically in Java? I don't know what your 2nd bullet is all about.

Comment: Did you mess classes with objects of those classes? to me "class A can have only one of the subclasses D or C of the super class B" does not make any sense... sorry. From your diagram there is absolutely no reason to have Class B in between A and C/D classes. What is purpose od class A there? can it be just one super class for C and D?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I know how to use constraints but the software that I am using won't allow me to add them on the association link (starUML)

Comment: @Vadim I'll give you a more concrete example: class A is the basket of fruit, class B is the superclass fruit, class C and D are a specific types of fruits. I want an instance of the class A to contain objects of type C xor D.

Comment: What's wrong with the UML that you have?

Comment: I can't seem to find an alternative for adding Xor constraint on the association link. i thought if i add the cardinality '1' on the superclass, then i can assure that the class A contains an object of class D or an object of class C. because if not you can never know the class of the object that the class A contains

Comment: H-m-m... fruit is not subclass of "basket of fruits"... that is a problem with Class structure. Do you not see this mistake in your example? Basket of fruits *uses* class fruit, but it is not a super class for it... Basket can be super class for things like "plastic basket of fruits", "large basket of fruits" etc...

Comment: So please correct you UML with regards to the `1`  since the fruit basket will likely have `0..n` fruits.

Comment: What's that going to be? Hide and seek? Please stick to a single question!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the max multiplicity of 1, all your example diagram is missing is a generalization set that is {complete, disjoint}. Your diagram now says {incomplete, overlapping}, by default, which means an instance can be a member of both A and B, or just a member of GPS.

Answer (score 0):

What about using generics like this:

```
public class A<T extends B> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class B {
}

public class C extends B {
}

public class D extends B {
}
```

Then you will instantiate class A with the desired subtype of B like this:

```
A<C> a = new A<>();
C c = new C();
D d = new D();
a.getList().add(c); //works fine
a.getList().add(d); //compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the fruit basket from your comment, you need to specify a multiplicity for `0..n` instead of the `1`.

If you want all instances to be the same subclass you need to add a constraint in any way. If your tool does not permit it, just add a note with `{ all instances of`B`must have the same type }` or the like.